# How can I set "toXDelta" translate animation value from java code?

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

how can I set toXDelta value from java code? I need to calculate it first so I can't just use final value in xml. I could use animate().translateX on my view but then I can't make animation slowing down till the end.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Viewfiliper** Method. Refrence is : [ViewFlipper | Android Developers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGiYq5scLJAhUEYg8KHdBnAOIQFggpMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FViewFlipper.html&usg=AFQjCNFul8SdYdyMNKlvzLqfN4_-fqfhgg)

There is an example in this.([Android ViewFlipper Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/))

And you make a  custum animation  in your code(See **res/anim**  Folder)

This is example code:

The MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.viewflipperapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private float lastX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    }

    // Using the following method, we will handle all screen swaps.
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            lastX = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();

            // Handling left to right screen swap.
            if (lastX < currentX) {

                // If there aren't any other children, just break.
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                    break;

                // Next screen comes in from left.
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
                // Current screen goes out from right. 
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

                // Display next screen.
                viewFlipper.showNext();
             }

            // Handling right to left screen swap.
             if (lastX > currentX) {

                 // If there is a child (to the left), kust break.
                 if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                     break;

                 // Next screen comes in from right.
                 viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
                // Current screen goes out from left. 
                 viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

                // Display previous screen.
                 viewFlipper.showPrevious();
             }
             break;
         }
         return false;
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f5f5f5" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Windows PC"
                    android:textColor="#b7102f"
                    android:textSize="25dp">
                </TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/windows_pc" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ubuntu PC"
                    android:textColor="#191975"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" >
                </TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ubuntu_pc" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

All of bellow code is into the  **res/anim** directory:

slide_in_from_left.xml  (see into the screen):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

slide_out_to_left.xml  (see out of screen):

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

slide_in_from_right.xml (see into the screen):

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

slide_out_to_right.xml (see out of screen):

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
          android:fromXDelta="0%"
          android:toXDelta="100%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%"
          android:toYDelta="0%"
          android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Translate animation you can send that value on making object of it.

```
TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta);
```

you read it here::

> public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
>
> Added in API level 1
>   Constructor to use when building a TranslateAnimation from code
>
> Parameters
>
> fromXDelta Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
>
> toXDelta   Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
>
> fromYDelta Change in Y coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
>
> toYDelta   Change in Y coordinate to apply at the end of the animation

I hope it is your requirment

Comment: @curousi have linearlayout with 3 weight sum. inside linearlayout I have one relative layout with weight 1.  so when I animate button from relative layout its move only with relative layout but I want to animate to main linearlayout do you know any solutions for that?

Comment: I want to move right to left textview name "txt_count_point_minus"

Comment: In your linear layout you are adding relative layout dynamically?

Comment: view is moveing but its move to the child layout boundary

Answer (score 0):

Download the `nineolddroids` (http://nineoldandroids.com/) library and read the docs...

you should be able to get the thing done using either `x` or `xBy` methods.

Sample usage:

```
private void sortCardsAndShadowAnim() {
//        float bottom = getHeight();
    float activeCardTop;
    if (activeCardIndex == getChildCount() - 1) {
        activeCardTop = topHeaderDown;
        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(getChildAt(activeCardIndex)).y(activeCardTop).setDuration(SORT_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(shadows.get(activeCardIndex)).alpha(getShadowAlpha(activeCardTop)).setDuration(SORT_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
    } else {
        for (int i = getChildCount() - 1; i > activeCardIndex + 1; i--) {
            ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(getChildAt(i)).y(bottom).setDuration(SORT_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
            ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(shadows.get(i)).alpha(getShadowAlpha(bottom)).setDuration(SORT_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
        }
```

this code actually moves Views (cards) via Y-axis, as well as fading it out as it moves.